# Why does this GNU C variadic function return a huge number?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, variadic-functions

I'm looking at [this example](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Example.html#Variadic-Example) of a variadic function in C, written GNU.org. My OS is Debian 8.6.

Here's my slight variation on it, filename is `ex.c`:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int addEmUp(int count,...){
    va_list ap; // where list of arguments are stored
    int i, sum;

    va_start(ap,count); // initialize the argument list

    sum=    0;
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
        sum += va_arg(ap,int);  // get the next argument value

    va_end(ap); // clean up

    return sum;
}

int main(void){
    printf("%d\n", addEmUp(3,4,5,6));
    printf("%d\n", addEmUp(10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
    printf("%d\n", addEmUp(10,10,10,10));
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my makefile `_example.mak`:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
CFILE=ex

run:
    cc $(CFILE).c -o $(CFILE) $(CFLAGS)
    ./$(CFILE)
    rm -f $(CFILE)
```

The output when I open the terminal and run `make -f _example.mak`:

```
./ex
15
55
1141373223
rm -f ex
```

Why does the third `addEmUp()` print `1141373223`?

Comment: You passed an invalid length. There should be 10 subsequent arguments, but there are only 3. So its using garbage values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have undefined behavior.

You sent `10` as first argument, but you call `addEmUp()` with only 3 additional arguments.

```
printf("%d\n", addEmUp(3, 10, 10, 10));
```

---

When you have an undefined behavior, you can't know what will happen. When your function `addEmUp()` get too far with `va_arg()`. You can cause a lot of thought:

- segmentation fault
- wrong behavior (what you get)
- etc

Like @user3553031 say in comment:

> Most likely, those other numbers that you're adding into sum are whatever else is on the call stack -- things like the saved return address and possibly even the current value of sum itself. This is strongly dependent on your operating system, compiler, and machine architecture; C does not define the structure of the call stack or even require that one exists.

Comment: Most likely, those other numbers that you're adding into `sum` are whatever else is on the call stack -- things like the saved return address and possibly even the current value of `sum` itself.  On some platforms, you may be throwing in a some register contents too.  This is strongly dependent on your operating system, compiler, and machine architecture; C does not define the structure of the call stack or even require that one exists.